# Why does R keep saying it could not find my function?

Tags: r

I'm just learning R and the problem says to create a function that will calculate the amount of tax on income. The first 50,000 is taxed 10% and the rest is taxed 20%. This is the function I created but anytime I try to call it I keep getting the error: 'could not find function "tax_calc"'.

```
    tax_calc<- function(income){
       if (income <= 50000){
          return (income*(0.10))
       } else {
          return ((50000*.1)+((income - 50000)*.2)
       }
    }
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try it on a fresh session

Comment: If you're in RStudio, you need to ensure it's been sourced properly. Select the function and hit Run

Comment: Does `tax_calc` appear in your variable explorer?  If you haven't run the lines of code which define the function, then R won't know the function exists.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function is not valid. Did you try to create it?

```
>    tax_calc<- function(income){
+        if (income <= 50000){
+           return (income*(0.10))
+        } else {
+           return ((50000*.1)+((income - 50000)*.2)
+        }
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"          return ((50000*.1)+((income - 50000)*.2)
       }"
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>
```

It should be:

```
tax_calc<- function(income){
    if (income <= 50000){
       return (income*(0.10))
    } else {
      return ((50000*.1)+(income - 50000)*.2)
   }
}
```

Now:

```
tax_calc(100000)
#[1] 15000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are laking a parenthesis at the end of the 5th line. Try running this function:

```
tax_calc<- function(income){
   if (income <= 50000){
      return (income*(0.10))
   } else {
      return ((50000*.1)+((income - 50000)*.2)) # Here I added the parenthesis
   }
}
```

Remember that to call a function you can either run the lines of code or source the function inside another script. For the latter, you can save your tax_calc function in a script, for example "TaxCalc_Script.R" or whatever. Then, when you need to use the function you can use the following:

```
source("TaxCalc_Script.R") # if the R script is in your working directory 
# or
source("C:/User.../WorkingDirectory/TaxCalc_Script.R") ## if the script is in a different folder
```

In this latter way, you can save several functions in one script. When you use `source()`, all the functions inside the script will be called into your environment.